# How to properly create heirarchy of dependency in dagger 2 in Android

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a couple of questions, since there is no decent documentation on Dagger 2. I am very new in programming, so the questions might be stupid

1) Is it ok to have only 1 component in application that consist of all modules.

2) It seems that you need to inject only from 1 component in the class  or all of the components must provide all of the @inject objects.

3) For instance, if in my application I have 2 different objects in 2 modules of the same type but for different purposes and 1 singleton object for whole app.
How do I inject singleton object and one of my 2 different objects for the certain purpose. How Dagger will understand what exact object do I want.